# USB2514B not working properly

Tags: usb, usb-hub

i'm using the USB2514B to create a 1 to 4 usb hub with some other relays. The problem is that when any device is connected, windows shows the "USB Device not recognized" error.
[image: scheme]
When using an oscilloscope on the usb output cable, **the USB D- pin is at 1V** or so, which I believe is wrong as it should be below 300mV when in idle. 5V, D+ at 3.3V and GND/Shield are all ok, and data transmission can be spotted on the oscilloscope on both D+ and D-.

Also, the XTAL signal is very dirty, with 400mV p-p around 1V again, instead of oscillating between 0V and 1.2V as written in the datasheet.

This voltage level is found only after the USB2514B, as the USB input low level is correctly below 300mV. Also, ground on this IC is difficult to check as the GND pin is under the pad. Design is pretty much similar to the reference one provided by MicroChip.

Do you think this IC is faulty or maybe I should check something in particular?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What does the layout look like? A ~90ohm transmission line impedance is needed.

Comment: i haven't designed the pcb, but I can say that it did work for a while, then stopped working. Other components are just relays, demultiplexer and ESD protection ICs, which have been all tested.

Comment: Then we'd need to know what your setup looks like or a screenshot from the scope.

Comment: Edited with the scheme. Also found out another issue on the xtal.

Comment: What do you mean "i haven't designed the PCB"? This kind of devices require careful board layout with heavy grounding of center slab, which is the main signal ground for the IC.